# Unique ideas for a computer science project for students?

Tags: project, computer-science

I'm starting my 3rd year in a Computer Science degree , and I need to pick a project and develop within the following year.

I'm searching for unique ideas for a project , I have some ideas , however I still have my doubts about them , whether or not they are good enough to develop and etc .

For example :

1. Client / Server application for supermarkets (food) with DB queries
2. Iphone application
3. Cellular dating system
4. ...

I'm sure that all of you (SO members) at some point of your careers came across (and still are) an interesting project (or projects) , so any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

4/ World grave database. Grave position (google maps) of every human (first and last name + birth and death date).

If this becomes some hit, I want % ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A mobile app that lets people friend each other, supports location services, allows you to display a map showing you where all of your friends are and click to send an SMS telling them to stay put because you're on your way.

It really depends on what your interests are, but if it were me I would focus on a project that lets me explore the possibilities of solving a problem via the integration of a broad range of technologies and architectures: a web or iPhone app with a social element that makes use of cloud resources and scaling technologies like Hadoop or Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I write networking code as my job. Here are some out-of-hours prototyping projects I've done recently, that might make it into our product in the next year. You want to pick something that's doable and has no external factors, so you can guarantee to get it working solidly.

- A WOL service. A central server maintains connections to client nodes, which check in through a service that runs when the machines are awake. They send their MAC on checkin. The channel must be secure, and only registered accounts can authenticate with the central server. Each machine runs a low-frequency broadcast service (UPnP-style) that advertises its presence to other machines on the service's network. When a node thinks it's picked up a signal from another node, it exchanges a challenge with it, and sends the result to the central server. Thus, the central server can validate that the machines are indeed 'adjacent' (able to contact each other directly), and that neither machine is lying about the location of the other.
  The point of this: if you have the login details for a node, the hosted service will relay a WOL instruction to any other node on the network which was known to be adjacent to the target node when it was last up. You can therefore wake your machine remotely when you don't access to its subnet, assuming at least one other machine on the subnet is turned on and checked into the service.
  That's an ambitious project, but possible for a motivated student with a good grasp of networking.
- Secondly, how about a VPN service? Do STUN on a central server to help two non-adjacent computers connect to each other and establish an SSH-style protocol with flow-controlled channels to perform port-forwarding (keep it simple: a SOCKS proxy on the client end is preferable to trying to do a full point-to-point network bridge with 'true' VPN capabilities).

I've got each of these to a working prototype in just under a day of coding each (using a few pre-written components from earlier), so for a student who's still learning C and network programming, they might be suitable year projects. I don't what level your university would push you to though.